# Creating email address from scratch

Tags: google-sheets

I have a set of data which includes first name, last name and company URL. I have created a drop down list to choose an email format from a list of 14 variations eg firstname@url.com or firstname.lastname@url.com

I'm after help with the formula to choose the appropriate format. I have a separate table to create the list of formats and formulas to concatenate based on selection.

VLOOKUP doesn't work, since the cell references will change. If you look at the sheet on the 'Email Data' sheet you'll see existing data and cells highlighted in red are where the formula need to be, based on the selection in the drop down box to the left.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16ZUU3d2eabEjnKSFUXFUkie4tLs2HAHdXMCCAO2mh4g/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you can do it: (check tab z cell G2)

```
=index(if(A2:A="",,substitute(substitute(
substitute(substitute(F2:F,"FN",A2:A),"LN",C2:C)
,"FI",left(A2:A)),"LI",left(C2:C))&"@"&E2:E))
```

The formula is simply substituting FN, LN, FI and LI respectively with the values in column A, C, first letter of column A and first letter of column C.

* You don't need `first initial` and `last initial` columns.

Comment: Sorry, one more question about your formula... When I drag the formula down into cells below, I get the error message "Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in G3". How can I copy this formula into an entire spreadsheet without getting this error?

Comment: @Alex, you don't have to drag the formula down. This is an array formula so it gets virtually dragged down automatically.

Comment: ahhhhh, light bulb moment! Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I could help! :) Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)